# how to access to a function inside a funtion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function inside a function outside the main one:

```
var myFunction = function myFunct(element) {
   function tryIt(){
          alert("hello");
   };
   return{
     tryIt: tryIt
  }
}
```

And I'm try to call "tryIt" function outside myFunct with

```
myFunction.tryIt
```

But it doesnt work.

how can I do this?

Comment: You should learn javascript properly. read more about [design patterns](http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/#design-patterns). Also [this](https://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/) is a good read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need is to call the function and then call the function of the returned object of the property `tryIt`.

```js
var myFunction = function myFunct(element) {
        function tryIt(){
            alert("hello");
        }
        return {
            tryIt: tryIt
        };
    };

myFunction().tryIt();
//        ^^            calls myFunction
// ^^^^^^^^^            returns object with function tryIt
//                ^^    calls tryIt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunct() { 
    function tryIt() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
    return {
        tryIt: tryIt
    };
}
var foo = myFunct();
foo.tryIt();
```